# Can Javascript be used to format HTML

Tags: javascript, html, formatting

I was just wondering if it is possible to format HTML using Javascript. Thanks a lot!

I am asking this as it is for an answer to a question in a practice paper for an exam. The question shows a fairly basic webpage and the question asks, "Which aspect of HTML allows for the formatting of the site". So I am wondering if javascript could be a valid answer

Comment: Can you be more specific, what do you mean by format HTML?

Comment: I am asking this as it is for an answer to a question in a practice paper for an exam. The question shows a fairly basic webpage and the question asks, "Which aspect of HTML allows for the formatting of the site". So I am wondering if javascript could be a valid answer

Comment: I'm not sure that JavaScript is an "aspect of HTML". It doesn't really have anything to do with HTML. (Well, except for those ridiculous String routines.)

Comment: Give the teacher an apple and ask them

Comment: The formatting of the site may be refering to the tags themselves. In such a case, each single tag can be a valid answer for formatting the HTML page. the <b> tag, as an example, is formatting a text, like the <i> tag and so on. Not sure if that's a valid answer, but it seems to logically be the closest answer to the question, right? In any case @charlietfl's comment is a way better solution. If he (the teacher) doesn't want to answer, give him/her two apples.

Comment: You have probably misunderstood the question in the paper. It seems to ask about formatting tools *in HTML*. JavaScript is not HTML. Neither is CSS. So the question appears to be about so-called presentational features in HTML (which is a complicated and controversial topic; e.g. `<b>` is presentational, for bolding, but HTML5 pretends to define it as “semantic” and not presentational).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The answer is no.

JavaScript can be used to do just about anything on a site including customizing the look and feel, changing colour, adding elements, applying classes, etc...

But Javascript is NOT an aspect of HTML as correctly pointed out in the comments below.

Comment: This is true **if** you think that JavaScript is an "aspect of HTML".

Comment: Pointy, you are right.  Javascript is not an aspect of HTML.  So the answer is "No" :P

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript** is not an aspect of **HTML**.

If the question is "which aspect of html allows the formatting of a site?", I would say your answer is **styling**, or more specifically, the **style attribute**.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_formatting.asp) is a more detailed explanation.

Or, because the question is not specific enough, the answer could be **html layouts**, since the style attribute would imply the use of **CSS**.

You can find out more about html layouts [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp).